# set timeouts dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, settimeout, cleartimeout

How to clean the timeout several hover elements?

The code I have is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".imagenesC").hover(imagenesCEntrada,imagenesCSalida);
});

var timeouts = {};  
function imagenesCEntrada(){
  var id=$(this).attr("id");
  clearTimeout(timeouts['cuadricula'][id]);
  $("#"+id).stop(true).animate({"opacity":"0"},1000); 
}

function imagenesCSalida(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    timeouts['cuadricula'][id] = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#"+id).stop(true).animate({"opacity":"1"},1000);
    }, 100);
}
```

A greeting

Comment: can you try to form key like `'cuadricula' + id` and avoid going for 2 dimension array notation like `['cuadricula'][id]`?

Comment: @Alonso: Check my answer, to see how we can apply multiple timeouts in array.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you've multiple elements with the same class, you can just use their index to create a dynamic array of timers.

See in working snippet.

```js
var timer = [];

$('.label').mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer[$(this).index()]);
    console.log("Mouse enter");
    $('#' + this.id + ' div').slideDown('slow');
});
$('.label').mouseleave(function(){
    var temp = $('#' + this.id + ' div');
    timer[$(this).index()] = setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log("Mouse leave");
        temp.stop().slideUp('slow');
    }, 2000);
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".imagenesC").hover(imagenesCEntrada,imagenesCSalida);
});

var timeouts = [];  
function imagenesCEntrada(){
  var id=$(this).attr("id");
  clearTimeout(timeouts[$(this).index()]);
  console.log("clear");
  $("#"+id).stop(true).animate({"opacity":"0"},1000); 
}

function imagenesCSalida(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    console.log("enter");
    timeouts[$(this).index()] = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#"+id).stop(true).animate({"opacity":"1"},1000);
    }, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label" id="dummyId1">Demo1</div>
<div class="label" id="dummyId2">Demo2</div>
<div class="label" id="dummyId3">Demo3</div>
<div class="label" id="dummyId4">Demo4</div>



<div class="imagenesC" id="imagenesC1">imagenesC1</div>
<div class="imagenesC" id="imagenesC2">imagenesC2</div>
<div class="imagenesC" id="imagenesC3">imagenesC3</div>
<div class="imagenesC" id="imagenesC4">imagenesC4</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!!
It was exactly what I needed.
You're the best!!

Comment: Glad to see that, accept the answer that will encourage others to use this solution :) All the best.